# How can I receive message from onClick event of web page using chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to catch click event from injected script on all tabs of chrome browser.

like below method

event.js is main javascript and test.js is injected js.

event.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: 'test.js'}, function(){
         console.log('executed'); 
        });
    }
});
```

test.js

```
var fragment = create('<div onClick="sendMessage to my extension">Hellow</div>');
document.body.insertBefore(fragment, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

how can I receive message from other website to my extenstion?
Is it impossible?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are properly injecting `test.js` as a content script (e.g. by declaring the appropriate properties in your ***manifest.json***), you need to make the following modifications:

In ***event.js*** add:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
    console.log('Tab with ID ' + sender.tab.id + ' sent a message:\n' + msg.text);
});
```

In ***test.js*** replace your code with:

```
var mydiv = document.createElement('div');
mydiv.textContent = 'Hello';
mydiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text: 'Someone clicked my DIV !' });
});
document.body.insertBefore(mydiv, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```